# Nginx custom internal error page when upstream is down

Tags: centos, nginx

I am new to Nginx and have a reverse proxy to an upstream glassfish server. I am trying to set up a custom 503 page for when the app is down for maintenance. I have been failing to do so for several hours now. The maintenance.html page contains a css and jpg link. These are showing up when I am forwarded to the maintenance page. All I get is the text of the page and a broken image.

CentOS 6.5
nginx 1.4.4 (from nginx repo)

```
upstream glassfish {
server <upstream IP>:8181 max_fails=1;
}

server {
 listen       80;
 server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

error_page  404 502   /static/error.html;
error_page  503      /static/maintenance.html;

location ~ ^/static/ {
    internal;
}

 location / {
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_pass https://glassfish;
 port_in_redirect off;
 }
}
```

The error that shows up in the access.log is

> [19/Dec/2013:17:49:17 -0500] "GET /static/main.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1136 "http:///
>   [19/Dec/2013:17:49:18 -0500] "GET /static/header-logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1136 "http:///

I have checked that /etc/nginx/html/static/header-logo.jpg  exists

I'm sure it's simple enough, but I just cannot figure it out!

Answer (score 4):

I recently wanted to do the same thing (show a nicer maintenance/error-page with images, CSS and custom fonts).

What I ended up doing was using an internal location block like this:

```
server {
  …

  error_page 502 = @maintenance;

  location @maintenance {
    root /path/to/maintenance-site;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^ /index.html break;
    }
  }
}
```

I wrote a [blog post](http://www.relativkreativ.at/articles/graceful-error-pages-with-nginx) about it, if you need more detail (has been down because I was rebuilding my infrastructure but is back up again).

Comment: The blog post you linked is no longer available.

Comment: Sorry - I'm currently reworking my websites and something went wrong obviously. The blog post is back online. Thanks for the info.

Comment: No worries :) I'm removing my downvote but apparently it needs an edit to the answer to unlock it.

Comment: Did a quick edit to allow removing of the downvote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You say you're doing this:

> ```
> location ~ ^/static/ {
>     internal;
> }
> ```

The `internal` keyword means that this `location` is only visible for internal requests, which your `error_page` requests are.

If you want to be able to access `/static/` directly from the web-browser, which would seem necessary in order to serve images referenced from the error pages, then you'd have to remove the `internal` directive from the said `location`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to do the following things:

- Use `inline CSS`
- Convert your images to `Base64`

After doing this, you can embed the generated Base64 string into the `background-image` CSS rule as follows:

```css
background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEADI.....==)
```

You can use the string with the `<img>` tags as well, just pass it to the `src` attribute as follows:

```html
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEADI.....==" />
```

This way you can keep the `internal` nginx rule.

Cheers!